# Behavior of Java's ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate()

Tags: java, concurrency, scheduling

I have a question regarding the [scheduleAtFixedRate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) method on ScheduledExecutorService in Java 6.

[***edit***: the Javadoc for 1.6 is more complete than that for 1.5. See comment below]

Given that:

- the ScheduledExecutorService is constructed with N = 1 thread in the pool
- the fixed-rate is a period of T seconds
- no initial delay

What happens in this case (times are not meant to be absolute, in the real-time sense):

- at time T, the service kicks off a Runnable task, "task1"
- at time 2T, task1 has not yet completed, and service is scheduled to fire

Is the service guaranteed to do any of the following?

- (a) at 2T, kick off a Runnable task, "task2" (recall N = 1)
- (b) block until task1 is finished
- (c) skip this time and try again at 3T
- (d) behavior is undefined

Or something else? Does the answer change if N > 1 ?

Comment: I was looking at the Java 1.5 doc (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29), which does not have the answer. When writing this question, I linked to the 1.6 doc without looking at it closely. As you'll see, the answer for 1.6 is evident.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is

> (b) block until task1 is finished

and that is regardless of number of threads of the executor (task2 might even be not submitted).

The doc says:

> If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, **but will not concurrently execute**.

(BTW, since there's no intial delay, "task1" will kickoff right away as doc`ed:

> executions will commence after initialDelay

).

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation that you linked...

> If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute.